# ON DELETE CASCADE in this case?

Tags: mysql, cascade, sql-delete

I need an advice on whether `ON DELETE CASCADE` is suitable to use in the following table

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    maincategory INT DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(maincategory) REFERENCES category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

In this case, ON DELETE CASCADE would simply delete all sub categories if the main category gets deleted.Is that the recommended approach ?

Comment: if you are talking about this thing only yes I think its good. but sometimes you need to do a fake delete (with a column named isDeleted) and when you do that. the `ON DELETE CASCADE` will not cause problem again so I say do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a tabular representation of a tree structure. You are using the adjacency model, storing the id of the parent in `maincategory` field (usually it is called parent_id).

Yes, this approach is totally valid. Using `ON DELETE CASCADE` you are securing yourself from the DELETE anomalies.

I would also recommend you to read about nested sets - this is a very efficient technique for representing trees in SQL:

http://www.evanpetersen.com/item/nested-sets.html

[How to represent a data tree in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175882/how-to-represent-a-data-tree-in-sql)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

And this book: Joe Celko "Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties"

Comment: thanks, great answer! I have similar design issue with one of my tables, maybe you could help me? I have a table Product that references Category table.Now, I have set in Product table FOREIGN KEY category_id with ON DELETE SET NUL and ON UPDATE CASCADE, so when Category gets deleted Product still remains in table, is that smart to have? Thanks once again.

Comment: @Zed If you want to keep the product after the category delete, this approach is correct. Plz, accept the answer if it's ok.