# Find all parents sql query with in a single table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have a table:

```
Id | child | parent 
 1      67         0 
 2      69        67 
 3      79        68 
 4      76        69 
 7      75        68
```

I want to select records until parent id is zero

All records in same table

Comment: Please provide an output example and the code that you have tried.

Comment: select * from table_1 c,table_1 where c.ID=P.Parent and c.Parent !=0

Comment: Is it a tree? Please explain the semantics of attributes. Output example for your data would be useful.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql

Comment: Yes it is tree 
But My query not work I am new to sql

Comment: For inspiration, have a look at the Recursive Common Table Expressions on [this refman page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Thanks for reply 
But I want ancestors of children and path from children id to top parent

Comment: @Ankit  Can you then please edit your question, explain that and include some expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from [How to represent a data tree in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175882/how-to-represent-a-data-tree-in-sql)

> some databases, particularly MySQL, have some issues in handling this model, because it requires an ability to run recursive queries which MySQL lacks.

A long but very thorough explanation of the problem (and its solution) can be found here: [Managing hierarchical data in mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

TL/DR: If you want to solve this problem with a single query then you need to change your tree to a nested list structure - which is a bit harder to understand but more efficient to handle in mysql.

Let's take this tree:

- A

  - B
  - C

    - D
    - E
  - F

In your adjacency list format this would look like this

```
id | text | parent
1    A
2    B      1
3    C      1
4    D      3
5    E      3
6    F      1
```

Getting all parents of node D is not easy.

Now we convert this to a nested set:

```
0_________________A__________________11
  1_B_2   3_______C_______8   9_F_10
            4_D_5   6_E_7

id | text | lft | rgt
1    A      0     11
2    B      1     2
3    C      3     8
4    D      4     5
5    E      6     7
6    F      9     10
```

Now getting all parents of node D is easy:

```
SELECT p.* FROM nestedset p
INNER JOIN nestedset o ON o.lft > p.lft AND o.rgt < p.rgt
WHERE o.text == "D"
```

As for how to do other operations, follow the link i posted.

Comment: Well, that's one solution

Comment: Thanks for reply 
But I want ancestors of children and path from children id to top parent