# How to create a tree structure data in SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC Model fist

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-relationship, ef-model-first

I need to save a **Tree Structure** Data into my database.

At first, I used **XML** as a attribute to perform this use case, but then I met some **concurrency** issues.

Now I decide to use table **relationship** to perform a tree structure, but still met some problems:

in my use case, a **TaskRoot** is a root of the tree, and a **TaskGroup** is a child tree, a **Task** is a leaf node which has no children.

Something look like :

[image]

Here this what I try in Model first, (sorry for chinese)

[image]

Then I add `On Delete Cascade` on the parent side.

An error occurs:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_NestedTaskGroup' on table 'TaskGroupSet' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

That makes more sense to delete all the children if the parent node is deleted.

Please tell me how better to save a tree structure?

Comment: Did you try _adjacency list_? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175926/6426692 -

Comment: I guess you are looking out for a Hierarchical Query using a Recursive CTE.

Comment: @Sami Um... I don't understand exactly, didn't I use an adjacency list ? I also stored **id  parent_id  data** .