# Datatype or structure for tree-search

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am using a Big Data structure that describes a tree of items by string labels, like path-string in a file system. There are ~198,000 tree-elements and ~9,100,000 leaf-elements.

Options to implement:

- by [**data type `ltree`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) that seems the natural choice.
- by **normalized table structure**: creating a serial index for each path, etc. and **recursive search**

I am supposing that, after implemented, I can compare both by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. But, **before to implement**, is possible to predict difference or to estimate (velocity and extra-disck consumption) performance ?

---

### NOTES AND TESTS

About queries (requirements), it is open: **the "hierarchical search engine" must be expressive**, ltree, regular expression and sometimes LIKE operator are all expressive when you is representing hierarchical informartion by "string paths".

Using for test a Guide's similar `CREATE TABLE test (path ltree)` with the ~198,000 tree-elements:

```sql
    CREATE INDEX path_gist_idx ON test USING GIST (path)
    ; -- consumes ~3G
    SELECT count(*) n 
    FROM test WHERE path ~ 'first.second.*.etc_etc_etc.*'
    ; -- n= 149068
    EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
      SELECT count(*) n 
      FROM test WHERE path ~ 'first.second.*.etc_etc_etc.*'
    ;  -- Planning Time: 0.075 ms
       -- Execution Time: 1317.443 ms
```

Comment: Guessing performance is palm reading.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, thanks.... So, my guess was correct, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`  (after developed alternative solution) is the only way. Well: delete the question or wait for a "palm reader"?

Comment: `ltree` definitely seems to be the best choice if you have path-string data. Apart from the amount of data, what volatility do you expect, and what kind of queries are you going to run?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I edited the notes on the question... But the context is open, "Data Mining" and "BI analysis", so powerful (most expressive set of hierarchical operators) is better.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for normalized table seems the "Closure Table", as recommended by this [this question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297827/287948).

On other indexing strategies, we can use the clues of [this question/answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21648/90651), that suggest to try `pg_trgm` module. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Let's check all solutions.

---

### Brute force (indexing)

The advantage of "brute force" is the no-demand on changes in data structure, only adding an index, is that on Big Data context we have some extra disk-space. So, only tested indexing, no split into real tree and pointers.

#### Test `ltree` searching

See tests on the body of the question. Execution Time: ~1300 ms.

Good hierarchy-search operators. Only problem is the need for a new column for the index, when the string must be preserved for another use, or not in the `ltree`-ingestion format. I used the convertion

```sql
trim(
  replace( 
   regexp_replace(text_path,'[^A-Z0-9_/]+','_','ig'), -- clean
   '/',  -- the path separator at text_path
   '.'   -- the ltree separator
  ),
  '.'  -- clean
)::ltree
```

So, when you transform, other problem, it is not 100% reversible for reuse by cast `ltree2text()`.

#### Test `pg_trgm` searching with LIKE operator

This is the faster way: ~200 ms

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX textpath_gist_idx  ON t2_text USING gin (txt_path gin_trgm_ops);
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
   SELECT count(*) n
   FROM   t2_text  
   WHERE  txt_path LIKE 'first/second/%/etc_etc_etc/%'
; --  Planning Time: 0.133 ms
  --  Execution Time: 195.524 ms
  -- ... BUT, returns zero on COUNT result!
```

The indexation `USING gin (colName gin_trgm_ops)` use less disk space, ~2G.

The problem here is not performance but that it not works (!), and is not the problem of the "two `%`" because works fine with similar query, so it **is not reliable**:

- COUNT `WHERE txt_path LIKE 'first/second/%/etc_etc_etc/%'` is zero.
- COUNT `WHERE txt_path LIKE '%etc_etc_etc%'` is correct.

Seems a PostgreSQL v12 bug (same for other versions?).

#### Test `pg_trgm` searching with regular expression

With execution time of ~1000 ms, it is a little bit faster (and less disk consumption) than `ltree`  and **most reliable** tham LIKE operator.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
   SELECT count(*) n
   FROM   t2_text  
   WHERE  txt_path ~ '^first/second/.+/etc_etc_etc/'
--  Timing: Generation 2.312 ms, ..., Total 27.853 ms
--  Execution Time: 1017.293 ms
```

### Closure Table

Need to add an `id bigserial` if not exists and a new table with *ancestor* and *descendant* pointing to original table. It **consumes more disk space** and ...Can I do all queries with this model?

It also consumes more **programmers time** (!), there are no automatized  way (it is a template-table but PostgreSQL not offers a ''standard solution'') to create the extra-table. For queries, **no simple operator**.

...so I not add a test, it is a Wiki: if you edit something here I can add a test to show differences.

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2_treeclosure (
   ancestor bigint NOT NULL,
   descendant bigint NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ancestor,descendant),
   FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES t2_text(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES t2_text(id)
 );
```

... sometimes is possible to reduce disk consumption of original `t2_text` table reducing text, after slipt it.  Need a function to reconstruct path, etc. but can be fast if ''table closure'' is faster tham "brute force"  methods.

Comment: "*no automatized way to create closure table*" - you could do with materialised views or triggers.