# SqLite: How to remove nodes from root to leafs in a tree with constant height?

Tags: sql, sqlite

We have tree structures represented by three tables in SqLite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "root_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "inner_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "parent"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "leaf_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "parent"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Say, for the sake of this example the height of the tree is 3 (root node, inner node and leaf node layer). But in practice there may be several, but constant, number of inner node layers.

Given a root node, I need to delete all of its descendant inner and leaf nodes and return the leaf nodes deleted. Ideally in a single SQL statement.

My first attempt was to do nested DELETE FROM statements, like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM leaf_nodes WHERE parent IN (
    DELETE FROM inner_nodes WHERE parent IN (
        DELETE FROM root_nodes WHERE id = ? RETURNING id
    ) RETURNING id
) RETURNING id
```

But later I learned that `RETURNING` is only available in [top-level `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html), so that seems to be a dead end.

We currently have this implemented using triggers, but (AFAIK) that doesn't work if we need to collect the deleted leaf nodes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297827/1030675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider utilising a combination of

1. Foreign Keys to automate the deletion of children by using `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and
2. a table to collect deletion ids, and
3. 3 `AFTER DELETE` triggers to automatically populate the insertions into the collection table.

This would allow the deleted id's to be obtained as and when wanted

Here's a demo:-

```
/* just in case cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS leaf_nodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inner_nodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS root_nodes;

/* Make sure that Foreign Key handling is enabled */
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;

/* The original tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "root_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "inner_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "parent"    INTEGER NOT NULL /*>>>>>>>>>> ADDED >>>>>>>>>>*/ REFERENCES root_nodes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "leaf_nodes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "parent"    INTEGER NOT NULL /*>>>>>>>>>> ADDED >>>>>>>>>>*/ REFERENCES inner_nodes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    -- other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
/*<<<<<<<<<< NEW TABLE FOR THE COLLECTION OF DELETED IDs >>>>>>>>>>*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deletion_log (timestamp INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')), type TEXT, deletedId INTEGER); 
/*<<<<<<<<< 3 AFTER DELETE TRIGGERS >>>>>>>>>>*/
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS leaf_nodes_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON leaf_nodes
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO deletion_log (type,deletedid) VALUES('3LN',old.id);
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS inner_nodes_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON inner_nodes
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO deletion_log (type,deletedid) VALUES('2IN',old.id);
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS root_nodes_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON root_nodes
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO deletion_log (type,deletedid) VALUES('1RN',old.id);
    END
;
/* DEMONSTRATE THE ABOVE */
/* 1 Load some root_nodes */
WITH cte_count(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM cte_count LIMIT 10)
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO root_nodes SELECT * FROM cte_count;

/* 2 Load some inner_nodes (approx 10 per root) */
WITH cte_count(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM cte_count LIMIT 100)
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO inner_nodes SELECT *,(abs(random() % 10)) + 1 FROM cte_count;
/* 3 Load some leaf_nodes again approx 10 fir inner node */
WITH cte_count(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM cte_count LIMIT 1000)
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO leaf_nodes SELECT *,(abs(random() % 100)) + 1 FROM cte_count;

/* Show the data after the initial load */
SELECT * FROM deletion_log ORDER BY type ASC; /*<<<<<<<<<< RESULT 1*/
SELECT * FROM root_nodes 
    JOIN inner_nodes ON inner_nodes.parent = root_nodes.id
    JOIN leaf_nodes ON leaf_nodes.parent = inner_nodes.id
ORDER BY root_nodes.id,inner_nodes.id,leaf_nodes.id /*<<<<<<<<<< RESULT 2*/
;
/*!!!!!!!!!! DELETE SOME ROOT NODES !!!!!!!!!!*/
DELETE FROM root_nodes WHERE (id % 2) = 1;
/* Show the data after the deletions */
SELECT * FROM deletion_log ORDER BY type ASC; /*<<<<<<<<<< RESULT 3*/
SELECT * FROM root_nodes 
    JOIN inner_nodes ON inner_nodes.parent = root_nodes.id
    JOIN leaf_nodes ON leaf_nodes.parent = inner_nodes.id
ORDER BY root_nodes.id,inner_nodes.id,leaf_nodes.id /*<<<<<<<<<< RESULT 4 */
;

/* Cleanup after demo */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS leaf_nodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inner_nodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS root_nodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deletion_log;
```

**Result of a run**

- Note that due to the random generation of data, the results will vary per run

***Result 1***

[image]

- As expected,  the delete_log table is empty, i.e. no deletions have been done as yet.

***Result 2***

[image]

- not very useful other than obviously some data is being loaded (but note that the first id is the id of the root_nodes and that 1 exists)

***Result 3***

[image]

and some 60 rows later

[image]

- obviously sorted to suit demonstration (root_nodes id, inner_nodes id, then leaf_node id)
- as can be seen all 3 types have rows
- root_nodes 1,3,5,7 and 9 have reportedly been deleted (as expected as the delete was to delete odd numbered id's).

***Result 4***

[image]

All this shows is that the first rows output are for root_nodes id 2, there are no rows for root_nodes id 1 (or 3,5,7 or 9)